# Methodical approach to improve deep neural network performance?

Tags: neural-network, classification, keras

Working on a binary classification task to identify duplicate documents with 350,000 labeled samples, 70 features. There is about a 10:1 class imbalance. My best performing model so far has been a random forest, but I would like to see if I can use a deep feed forward neural network for better results.

I have been playing with the number of layers and hidden units and verify performance using 5-fold cross validation. Here is an example of one architecture:

```
for train_validation, test_validation in sfk.split(X_train,y_train):   
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(150, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dense(125, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(75, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train.iloc[train_validation,:].values,
              y_train.iloc[train_validation].values.reshape([-1,1]),
              epochs=13,
              batch_size=64,
              verbose=2,
              validation_data=(X_train.iloc[test_validation ,:].values,y_train.iloc[val_test].values.reshape([-1,1])))
```

I run that, get the mean/std of the accuracy and error. Then try adding a layer, removing a layer, adding some units, removing some. There is movement in accuracy and error (in the +/- 0.00x range). This approach is unscientific, what is a better way?

Comment: If you are using cross-validation correctly to measure performance, then I would say your approach *is* scientific. In that you create a hypothesis ("this model may be better") design an experiment (build the model and train it) then use measurements to test it and come to a conclusion ("no it is not better"). It might not be efficient though, if you are randomly trying different model hyper-parameters based on guesses.